Select Columns From Active Cell With Offset and Rows Based on Active Cell Value
I'm trying to select a Range using VB based on some specific criteria, example table is below.
Ex.

If the Active Cell is A1 ("TEST 1") then SELECT F through J and down for all "TEST 1" cells.

If the Active Cell is A4 ("TEST 2") then SELECT F through J and down for all "TEST 2" cells.

And so on for "TEST 3"...

The range "F through J" will always be F through J.

Ideally I could select ANY "TEST 1" cell and it would select all "TEST 1" Rows at Columns F through J.


The code below will select the Columns I need but the Rows are hardcoded and not based on the Column A value.
Sub SelectCurrentGroup()
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(2, 5), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9)).Select
End Sub

Any Help is appreciated!



A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J




TEST 1











TEST 1











TEST 1











TEST 2











TEST 2











TEST 3











TEST 3











TEST 3













If your selection is in Column A and you run this code, it will select all matching rows:
Sub SelectRangeBasedOnCriteria()
    Dim searchValue As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rngToSelect As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    searchValue = ActiveCell.Value

    ' Find the last row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    ' Loop through column A to find matching rows
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
        If cell.Value = searchValue Then
            If rngToSelect Is Nothing Then
                Set rngToSelect = ws.Range("F" & cell.row & ":J" & cell.row)
            Else
                Set rngToSelect = Union(rngToSelect, ws.Range("F" & cell.row & ":J" & cell.row))
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Select the final range
    If Not rngToSelect Is Nothing Then
        rngToSelect.Select
    Else
        MsgBox "No matching rows found."
    End If
End Sub



Thank you this is great. I just thought of a tweak that would be nice - is it possible to make this work if the Active Cell is ANY cell within the "TEST 1" Range? So ANY cell within A2:A4 and J2:J4. For ex. if the Active cell is G4, then the selection is still the same. Does that make sense? So it would still use Column A for the Search value but the Column A value in relation to the ActiveCell.

@nok - just change searchValue to searchValue = Cells(ActiveCell.row, 1).Value

A very short solution for the active sheet utilizing the Excel power:
Option Explicit

Sub SelectRanges()
  Dim address$
  address = "A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  On Error Resume Next
  Range(Application.Evaluate("TEXTJOIN("","",TRUE,LET(arr,FILTER(ROW(" & address & _
    ")," & address & "=""" & ActiveCell.text & _
    """),MAP(arr,LAMBDA(I,""F""&I&"":J""&I))))")).Select
End Sub

